# Why do we sometimes write reactants above the reaction arrow?

Tags: notation

We write:

\[\ce{Alcohol ->[\ce{KMnO4}] Acid}\]

The alcohol forms a carboxylic acid, i.e. gains an $\ce{O}$ from $\ce{KMnO4}$. This means $\ce{KMnO4}$ is a reactant! Then why is it written above the arrow?

What else do we write above the arrow?

Comment: If we only care about what happens to alcohol it's useful notation.

Comment: Btw, if you're interested in using $\LaTeX$ for math and equations and really want really sharp looking chemical equations, have a look at all the options provided by the `mhchem` package. Check out [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) and the original documentation at [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf). You will love it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things written on arrows are chemicals that are part of the reaction in some way, but not one of the reactants or products. In this case, the $\ce{KMnO4}$ is your oxidizing agent, which can be swapped out for any other strong oxidizer, and is not an inherent part of the reaction.

Other things you could see on the arrow would be $\ce{H2O}$ or Diethyl Ether, both of which are solvents. Other things include $h\nu$ and $\Delta T$, both of which are conditions under which the reaction takes place. Lastly the most common thing you'll see are catalysts such as $\ce{Pt}$. As you  can see, all of these things are necessary to the reaction, but aren't really what we care about in the reaction/can be substituted for other, similar chemicals.

Comment: but why cant we call it a reactant. also is it a reagent ? Can we call KMnO4 a reagent?

Comment: Does KMnO4 provide oxygen atom to acid?

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Is KMnO4 a reagent here? Thanks very much wes3449 ..

Comment: @Princess Yes, it does provide the oxygen and calling it a reagent is fine. Wow, two answers in one :)

Comment: @Princess, a reagent is the same as a reactant. Just two different ways of saying the same thing. If you want more info about the full reaction, you should look for the full reaction mechanism.

Comment: Do we write reagent name at top of arrow?

Comment: If you want to write a proper balanced chemical equation then you do **not** write reagents on the arrow!  Catalysts, energy sources, environmental conditions, yes...

Comment: So where do I write KMnO4? @User58220

Comment: On the left, with the other reagents...  See equations in http://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/acids/preparation.html

Comment: @wes3449 In case of light and heat are these reactants?